# PHP Mcrypt_decrypt decrypt only parts of the original string

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have a weird problem regarding passing an encrypted string through url. I'm using base64 encryptions from mcrypt() for encryptHTML() and decryptHTML().

I have this piece of code to encrypt:

```
$link_string = http_build_query(array('index_number'=>30843854, 'extra_attendence_id'=>27982423, 'target_temporary_id'=>378492085, 'date'=>'2016-05-06', 'action'=>'OUT', 'target_id'=>390234), '', '&');
$link_string = encryptHTML($link_string);
```

then I passed it through this url:

```
'localhost/website/controller/action/'.$link_string
```

then I decrypted it with this piece of code:

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
$id = decryptHTML($id);
parse_str($id, $arr_id2); 
var_dump($arr_id2);
```

I will get these in return, as expected:

```
array(6) { ["index_number"]=> string(8) "30843854" ["extra_attendence_id"]=> string(8) "27982423" ["target_temporary_id"]=> string(9) "378492085" ["date"]=> string(10) "2016-05-06" ["action"]=> string(3) "OUT" ["target_id"]=> string(6) "390234" }
```

The next case is when I still want the encrypted link but I need to attach some other value from DOM element in the page, so I tried to

```
'localhost/website/controller/action/encrypt='.$link_string.'&DOMvalue=10000'
```

then I modified the decryption with this piece of code:

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
parse_str($id, $arr_id2); 

$the_DOMValue = $arr_id2['DOMvalue'];

$id = decryptHTML($arr_id2['crypted']);
parse_str($id, $arr_id);
var_dump($the_DOMValue); echo "<br>";
var_dump($arr_id);
```

But then, I get these in return, to my surprise:

```
string(5) "10000" 
array(3) { ["index_number"]=> string(13) "58_2016-04-26" ["extra_attendence_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["target_t"]=> string(0) "" }
```

My original string was cut short! Note that the DOMvalue is fine.
Then, I checked that right before both decryption, if the given encrypted string is different:

on first case of decryptHTML:

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
var_dump($id);
$id = decryptHTML($id);
```

returns:

```
string(224) "zCQnh-rNP2R7h4UHyV5Dm5zp494DIIku5LWN51yYGMXBaHf0gJgEDw8UCuHRZxr-CkjkevHQ70kOPnSBQ9CJP6lZrFone-nDMDJhYlL8330wz+zud8-3tSWvdOLB7je5D-22aX4OrE3zlBYZZZtI-rMT73H0JGIRzZge2GzcZGLwS7Rj+GL5Ym-ET6JEHDShST4etgcQaEYXml-+BZ2+0BQKvubZEBOB"
```

on the second case of decryptHTML:

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
parse_str($id, $arr_id2); 

$the_DOMValue = $arr_id2['DOMvalue'];           
var_dump($arr_id2['crypted']);
$id = decryptHTML($arr_id2['crypted']);
```

returns:

```
string(224) "zCQnh-rNP2R7h4UHyV5Dm5zp494DIIku5LWN51yYGMXBaHf0gJgEDw8UCuHRZxr-CkjkevHQ70kOPnSBQ9CJP6lZrFone-nDMDJhYlL8330wz zud8-3tSWvdOLB7je5D-22aX4OrE3zlBYZZZtI-rMT73H0JGIRzZge2GzcZGLwS7Rj GL5Ym-ET6JEHDShST4etgcQaEYXml- BZ2 0BQKvubZEBOB"
```

It looks exactly the same to me, but strangely it was decrypted differently. I of course used the same functions to decrypt both cases...

Anybody can shed me some light on this?

Comment: _imo_, I suggest that you don't use base64_encode / decode when you are using the string in a URL. Why? It gets encoded again. It is the one place in HTML that _base64_encode / decode_ should not be used.  Look at: [urlencode — URL-encodes string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) instead. Or, convert to a hex string (`bin2hex`) and (`hex2bin)`.  Longer but perfectly safe to use anywhere in HTML..

Answer (score 1):

> passing an encrypted string through url

[Passing an encrypted string through a URL](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) is a bad idea. Full stop.

> I'm using base64 encryptions from mcrypt() for encryptHTML() and decryptHTML().

Without seeing what these functions do, this isn't helpful information, but [mcrypt should be avoided](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong). Use Libsodium (if you can; otherwise, use OpenSSL) instead.

> My original string was cut short!

It probably treated the + as a space. Using `urlencode()` would fix one problem, but it wouldn't solve the [vulnerability to chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) that using mcrypt introduces into your application in the absence of a Message Authentication Code (MAC).